Android - Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
Trying to teach myself android and following a tutorial.
I am recieving the following error: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView.
There is a previous post on the same question (Error inflating class android.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView, can someone tell me what I'm missing), but the error on there seems to be related to startDestination being not defined. In my case there seems to be a value.
Any suggestion on what I am doing wrong?
Logs
Java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.geofenceapp/com.example.geofenceapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24 in com.example.geofenceapp:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #24 in com.example.geofenceapp:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView

MainActivity.kt
package com.example.geofenceapp

import android.os.Bundle
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.navigateUp
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import com.example.geofenceapp.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint

@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    }

}

activity_main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:visibility="visible">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/navHostFragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="729dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


Error is pointing to line 24 of your XML file, which is app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph", so check if that file exists or if there's any syntax error in it or not.

It seems to check out: nav_graph can be found in path: navigation/nav_graph.xml. I cannot see any issue.

@Yamin: you put me in the right direction. nav_graph.xml was referring to a file that I created as a Kotlin file instead of a class by mistake. Somehow the laptop got a bit upset after that change, I had to reboot it. Now the app launches without any error.
